# JDBC Connection on Current Primary Database After Switchover: ORA-01033 encountered

Tags: oracle, high-availability, jdbc, dataguard

We are using Oracle Data Guard and currently testing Disaster Recovery scenarios, which is starting the application after switching over from the Primary Database to the Secondary Database.

I am using the following connection string as per [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HABPT/config_fcf.htm#HABPT5381):

```
(DESCRIPTION_LIST=
    (LOAD_BALANCE=off)
    (FAILOVER=on)

    (DESCRIPTION=
        (ADDRESS_LIST=
            (LOAD_BALANCE=on)
            (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=PROD_DB_1)(PORT=1521))
            (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=PROD_DB_2)(PORT=1521))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=PROD_DB))
    )

    (DESCRIPTION=
        (ADDRESS_LIST=
            (LOAD_BALANCE=on)
            (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DR_DB_1)(PORT=1521))
            (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DR_DB_2)(PORT=1521))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=DR_DB))
    )

)
```

The scenario is that we are now switched over to the secondary database, so the application should now connect to `DR_DB`. However, when we try to connect, it still connects to the `PROD_DB`, because we're getting the following exception:

```
ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

This may be answered already in some threads, and I may not have searched hard enough, but I also do not know if I am expecting the correct result.

I do not expect the application's database connection to stay alive after a switch over; I only want to avoid reconfiguring the application whenever we do DR, and I expect that the above connection string will connect to whichever is the primary database. Is this correct?

Thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And that is why we use role-based services instead of the default service derived from `instance_name` and `db_unique_name`.

If your primary database is called `PROD_DB` (`db_unique_name`), there will be  service with that name at the primary site, and that service will be available even after a failover or switchover. The listener receives your request, sees that you are requesting to connect using the service `PROD_DB`, and forwards your request to the instance(s) that provide that service. The instance is in `MOUNT` stage, and you receive `ORA-01033`.

Create the role based service at both sites (replace -db and -service values with your current ones):

```
srvctl add service -db ORCL -service myservice -role primary
srvctl start service -db ORCL -service myservice -role primary
```

The `start` step will fail at the standby site, and the service remains in `INTERMEDIATE` state, but that is normal.

With this, the service is automatically relocated (stopped at old primary and started at new primary) when you perform a role transition with Data Guard broker.

And use this service for connecting:

```
(DESCRIPTION_LIST=
    (LOAD_BALANCE=off)
    (FAILOVER=on)

    (DESCRIPTION=
        (ADDRESS_LIST=
            (LOAD_BALANCE=on)
            (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=PROD_DB_1)(PORT=1521))
            (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=PROD_DB_2)(PORT=1521))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=myservice))
    )

    (DESCRIPTION=
        (ADDRESS_LIST=
            (LOAD_BALANCE=on)
            (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DR_DB_1)(PORT=1521))
            (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DR_DB_2)(PORT=1521))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=myservice))
    )

)
```

When you try to connect using the service `myservice`, and your client tries the first entry (old primary, currently standby), the listener refuses the connection as there will be no `myservice` service running at that site, and your client tries the next available address.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample Oracle net alias configuration for rac db on both in primary and in DR site. I don't see any issues on your netalias configuration but i wonder why don't you use SCAN names/VIP instead using hostname.

can you try with below configuration and update us.

```
SALES=
 (DESCRIPTION_LIST=
  (LOAD_BALANCE=off)
  (FAILOVER=on)
  (DESCRIPTION=     (CONNECT_TIMEOUT=5)(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(RETRY_COUNT=3)
    (ADDRESS_LIST=
      (LOAD_BALANCE=on) 
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=prmy-scan)(PORT=1521)))
    (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=oltpworkload)))
  (DESCRIPTION=
(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=5)(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(RETRY_COUNT=3)
    (ADDRESS_LIST=
      (LOAD_BALANCE=on)      
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=stby-scan)(PORT=1521)))
    (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=oltpworkload))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your recommendation, but it returns the same error (ORA-01033). Could it be a problem with the Listener configuration?

Comment: can you provide us the below details, 1. lsnrctl services (from DR)            2. tnsping <service_name>